# How to STOP my ExtJS panel from duplicating itself

Tags: extjs

I have a panel "Person" and inside of this panel I create another panel "Info" with some buttons to add functionality. There is yet another panel where you can choose from a list of "Person"'s. My problem is that when you select another "Person" from the overView panel that my "Info" button gets duplicated. So if you have clicked on 6 different "Person"'s that browser session, then you will have 6 different "Info" Panels within "Person".

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: describe how you are loading new person when chosen from a list. share the person panel's snippet where you are creating info panel. this snippet is probably in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do for a page with multiple selections is put the panel that gets recreated in a window. Then when you need to create another panel of the same type, you make a new window. Therefore you don't need to clear out the previous window.